# Typescript `declare global` preventing Jest test suites from running

Tags: typescript, jestjs

My app using react, redux, and jest has a typescript file with this code in it:

```
declare global {
  interface Window { eventSource: any;}

  class EventSource {
    errorers: any;
    onerror: any;
    onmessage: () => void;

    addEventListener(event: string, cb: () => void): void;

    constructor(name: string);
  }
}
```

I'm using the jest test framework to run tests on other areas in the app that use es6 javascript and they work fine.  Unfortunately, there are two test suites that are prevented from running because of because of the following error and another just like it:

```
/Users/blyncsy/Documents/blyncsyu/client/app/bundles/analytic/data-hub.ts:3
declare global {
        ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

  at transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/transform.js:321:12)
  at Object.<anonymous> (app/bundles/Pulse/actions/odAnalyzerActions.js:2:16)
  at Object.<anonymous> (app/bundles/Pulse/containers/od-analyzer/ODLineRenderer.js:6:26)
```

Other pieces of this same typescript file screw up the test runner if the one listed above is commented out.  This file is referenced in the actions file that is being tested in the first test suite, and an action from this file is being reference in the file being tested by the second suite.  I'm assuming something needs to be done to pre-compile this .ts file before it is encountered by the tests, but I have not been able to figure out how to do it.  Here is the webpack config:

```
/* eslint comma-dangle: ["error",
 {"functions": "never", "arrays": "only-multiline", "objects":
 "only-multiline"} ] */

const webpack = require('webpack');
const pathLib = require('path');

const devBuild = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

const config = {
  entry: [
    'es5-shim/es5-shim',
    'es5-shim/es5-sham',
    'babel-polyfill',
    './app/bundles/analytic',
    './app/bundles/Pulse/startup/registration',
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'webpack-bundle.js',
    path: pathLib.resolve(__dirname, '../app/assets/webpack'),
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({ NODE_ENV: 'development' }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /travel-info-type.ts/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'expose-loader',
          options: 'TravelInfoType'
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /heatmap-getter.ts/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'expose-loader',
          options: 'HeatmapGetter'
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /data-hub.ts/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'expose-loader',
          options: 'DataHub'
        }]
      },
      {
        test: require.resolve('react'),
        use: {
          loader: 'imports-loader',
          options: {
            shim: 'es5-shim/es5-shim',
            sham: 'es5-shim/es5-sham',
          }
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
      { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" },

      // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
      { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" },
      // Extract css files
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
};

module.exports = config;

if (devBuild) {
  console.log('Webpack dev build for Rails'); // eslint-disable-line no-console
  module.exports.devtool = 'eval-source-map';
} else {
  console.log('Webpack production build for Rails'); // eslint-disable-line no-console
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your error

> `/Users/blyncsy/Documents/blyncsyu/client/app/bundles/analytic/data-hub.ts:3`

Indicates Jest is trying to run a `.ts` file. You need to use `ts-jest` to transform this TS file.

## More

This is documented in the TypeScript docs : https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/getting-started.html#using-typescript

Comment: Yup, tried that, and it still gives the same error.

Comment: In fact, with that installed as specified in the linked docs, I get another error related to the `tsconfig.json` file: 
```    Some errors occurred while attempting to read from /Users/blyncsy/Documents/blyncsyu/client/tsconfig.json: {
        "messageText": "No inputs were found in config file 'tsconfig.json'. Specified 'include' paths were '[\"./src/**/*\"]' and 'exclude' paths were '[]'.",
        "category": 1,
        "code": 18003
    }```